# Grails map domain class custom column name

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In my Grails project I'm connecting to an existing DB and I'm having the following structure

```
class Country {
  Integer country
  String countryCode
  String label
}

class Address {
  String countryCode
  ....
}
```

### DB tables:

## country table

*id, version, country, country_code, label*

## address table

*id, version, country_code, ...*

I would like to have something like:

```
class Address {
  Country country
}
```

But it seems it is automatically looking for a column called `country_id` in the address table, I've tried using

```
static mapping = {
    country column: 'country'
}
```

But I'm still having the same result.

I know it would better to link it to the `country.id` but the DB is existing and I cannot modify it.

Anybody can help on this?

Comment: So is there a column `country` in your existing db table `address`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use one-to-many relationship, you do not need the property declared.
Under the `class Country` you can add

```
static hasMany = [addresses: Address]
```

And add

```
static belongsTo = [country: Country]
```

You don't need to add `Country country` field.

Then you can use `addressInstance.country.countryCode` in your view to display the data.

Comment: I've tried it but I'm receiving this error: `ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column this_.country_id does not exist`

Comment: I just reread your post and you cannot change the table. Did you try mapping `static mapping = {
    country column: 'country_code'
}`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html) and add to domain class `Country`:

```
static mapping = {
     id name: 'country'
}
```

Comment: I've tried it but I'm receiving this error: `ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column this_.country_id does not exist`